# Owner relation between classes in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have two classes: User and Dog. 
They are sorted in two different ArrayLists; userArrayList and dogArrayList.
When I want to list all my users, I also want to print the dogs they own. For example:

Command> list users

User1 [DogX, DogY]

User2 []

In this case User 1 owns two dogs, and User2 doesn't own any.

How do I implement this "owner" relationship between the two classes?

This is my list user method right now:

```
public void listUsers() {
        if (userArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: no users in register");
        } else {
            for (User user : userArrayList) {
                System.out.println(user.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I am trying to show the relation, but I cant figure out how to connect the list with the instance of the User.

```
boolean upForAuction = false;
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(auctions);
        for (int i = 0; i < auctions.size(); i++) {
            if (dName.equalsIgnoreCase(auctions.get(i))) {
                System.out.print("The auction is closed. The winning bid 
was ");
                System.out.println(bidArrayList.get(i).toString());
                List<String> ownedDogs = o.getOwnedDogs();
                ownedDogs.add(dName);
                upForAuction = true;
```

Comment: in your User class, add a List<Pet>. Make Dog a subclass of Pet.

Comment: It looks like you already have a `getOwnedDogs()` method, so why don't you just use it in your `for (User user : userArrayList)` loop?

Comment: So I also create a new class called Pet?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException because I need to link specific users to specific dogs. I haven't done that yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
class User {
private String userName;
private List<Dog> dogList;

public User(){}
public User(String name){
userName=name;
}

public void setDogLis(List<Dog list){
doglist=list;
}
public void setUserName(String name){
username=name;}

public List<Dog> getDogList(){
return dogList;}

public String getUserName(){
return userName;
}
}

class Dog {
private String dogName;

public Dog(){}
public Dog(String name){
dogName=name;
}

public void setDogName(String name){
dogName=name;}

public String getDogName(){
return dogName;
}
}

class Auction {
Dog dog1=new Dog("dog1");
Dog dog2=new Dog("dog2");
Dog dog3=new Dog("dog3");
Dog dog4=new Dog("dog4");

User user1=new User("user1");
User user2=new User("user2");

List<Dog> dogList1=new ArrayList(2);
doglist1.add(dog1);
doglist1.add(dog2);

List<Dog> dogList2=new ArrayList(2);
doglist1.add(dog3);
doglist1.add(dog4);

user1.setDogList(dogList1);
user2.setDogList(dogList2);

  }
```

and now, you have 2 users with 2 dogs

Also, You can have just `Map<String, List<Dog>>`, which can consist userName as String like KEY  and listDog as List like VALUE for that map.

Comment: What I dont understand is how do I do this without creating the instances myself?

Both users and dogs are/and should be created from within the program. 

Would it be more clear if I shared all my code?

Comment: It will be clear, of course. But what do you mean under _without creating the instances myself_ ? In my example, I created 2 Users and  4 dogs. If you can, show your code

Comment: I dont want to precode the dogs and the users. The User of the program will create them through commands.

Comment: Ok, it's a little bit hard to explain what should be changed :-) You have preset of dogs and users in the main class. I don't understand of ownership if you lists all dogs from new List in dogShell class

Comment: the only reason I have preset dogs and users in Main is because its makes my testing easier. In the final product there will not be any preset dogs or users

Comment: I see several variants:
1) It uses static class which would fill up and can be available from each class;
2) Is uses in DogShell `private List<User> users` which have `private List<Dog> dogs` inside it and that fields(list) will consist actual information in time but in start of program it'd be empty. That (2-nd) variant is shown in my answer

Comment: Okay, thanks I think I understand now. But do you have any idea on how I would fill the list up? If u take a look at close auction which is the last method in DogShell

Comment: List<String> auctions ?

Comment: Also, inside closeAuction() you initialize your `ArrayList ownedDogs = o.getOwnedDogs();` so Ownership can be common class for Dog and User and, possible for Auction classes. When you start the program, you'll create Dogs,Users and after setCommand startAuction you'll be, probably, lists through all your Lists.

Comment: And, As I wrote earlier, You can use Map<User,List<Dog>> or as you have now Map<User,Set<String>> where String is dogName